# MailScanner error "Cannot find Socket"

Tags: centos, email-server, centos7, clamav, mailscanner

CentOS 7, mail server. Messages stopped going in and out. Tried to debug, saw this in /var/log/maillog:

`MailScanner[4786]: Cannot find Socket (/var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock) Exiting!`

But the socket has correct permissions:

`srw-rw-rw- 1 clamscan clamscan 0 Jan 10 22:46 /var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock`

Please help to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to Google Translate, found an answer in Hungarian. :) https://hup.hu/node/160996

After update, the only string in /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/clamd.scan.conf changed:

from

`d /run/clamd.scan 0750 clamscan clamscan`

to

`d /run/clamd.scan 0710 clamscan virusgroup`

So, basically you need to change it back to `d /run/clamd.scan 0750 clamscan clamscan` (or whatever you had before update).

Thank you, krix from Hungary!